# How to use PEGjs for validation, instead of parsing?

Tags: pegjs

I have the following PEGjs productions:

```
NameStartChar = ":" / [A-Z] / "_" / [a-z] / [\u00C0-\u00D6] / [\u00D8-\u00F6] / [\u00F8-\u02FF] / [\u0370-\u037D] /
                [\u037F-\u1FFF] / [\u200C-\u200D] / [\u2070-\u218F] / [\u2C00-\u2FEF] / [\u3001-\uD7FF] /
                [\uF900-\uFDCF] / [\uFDF0-\uFFFD] / [\uD800-\uDB7F][\uDC00-\uDFFF]

NameChar = NameStartChar / "-" / "." / [0-9] / "\u00B7" / [\u0300-\u036F] / [\u203F-\u2040]

Name = NameStartChar NameChar*
```

I'd like to somehow get `true` if my input string matches `Name`, and `false` otherwise. I also don't care about parsing out the component parts.

However, PEGjs really wants to throw an exception if the match fails.

I could of course wrap it in a try/catch, but I'd prefer to avoid that. And I'd like to avoid collecting the parsed components as well (i.e., I don't need `["a", ["b", "c", "d"]]` when matching `"abcd"`, I just need `true`).

Is there some hidden PEGjs feature that will make this work? Maybe a clever action, or an innovative use of combinators?

Or perhaps I should be using an entirely different tool, and not a parser-generator? If so, does anyone know what I should be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Name { return true } / { return false }` to get an expression that will return true if the rule matched. Then, we can add `!.` to check that we are at the end of the input for the `true` case, and .* to skip to the end in the false case. So we get:

```
ValidateName = Name !. { return true } / .* { return false }
```

Answer (score 0):

The language of Names you define seems regular to me, so you could do it with a regular expression.
Depending on the language you use you would call a function match or find to test your input.

Remember to put begin and end of line anchors so it matches the entire input, for example

```
^(:|[A-Z]|_|etc)(:|[A-Z]|_|etc|-|\.|[0-9]|etc)*$
```

Comment: Yes, it definitely is, but I want to reuse the existing BNFs in specs instead of having to translate them to regular expression syntax.

Comment: @Domenic maybe this works (disclaimer because I have almost no experience with PEGs): add a rule  TestName = Name / .* with appropiate semantic actions on either side of /. The right side should match anything only if it wasn't a Name.

Answer (score -1):

```
ValidateName = Name { return true } / { return false }
```

If you want to validate input without advancing the parser position with a sub-expression you can use `&Name`.

Comment: This fails on `a!`, which should return `false` but instead throws an error.